# ArcObjects error storing long integer value to Oracle

Tags: arcobjects, oracle-spatial

I am trying to save a long integer value to an Oracle field. I have created a field of long integer type using ArcCatalog in a standalone table. The below code breaks at `row.set_Value(idx, val)` . Error message is:

> "The value type is incompatible with the field type.[EMP_ID]"

It looked such a trivial problem but now I am stuck. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```c#
IMxDocument doc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap map = doc.FocusMap;
IFeatureLayer layer = map.get_Layer(0) as IFeatureLayer;
IFeatureClass fc = layer.FeatureClass;
IWorkspace ws = (fc as IDataset).Workspace;

IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;
ITable tbl = fws.OpenTable("TestTable");
int idx = tbl.FindField("EMP_ID");
IRow row = tbl.CreateRow();
long val = 123412341234;
row.set_Value(idx, val);
row.Store();
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the `DESCRIBE tablename` output from SQL*Plus.

Comment: Note that "long" might be an 8-byte `long long` with some compiler switches, but `int` isn't likely to be anything other than a 4-byte type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long is not that long according to ESRI. They say it translates to [`number(10)`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/data-types-oracle.htm), while you need a `number(12)` or more. The workaround is to create a `double(12,0)` column in ArcCatalog, with a scale of 0 (no decimals). You can read it as .net long in your code. This [doc](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm) is also useful.

From experience, I have found default values chosen by ESRI to be sub-optimal.

Comment: yes JGH, long is not long enough for ESRI.